# Maximum page weight in mobile web application

Tags: android

I am developing an android application.I want to know what is maximum page weight recommended by best practises working group for mobile web application.I did searched for this,But cant find any solution.Can anyone guide me how to do this

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html

I personally use 100, but as far as i know, there's no "maximum'

android:weightSum

Defines the maximum weight sum. If unspecified, the sum is computed by adding the layout_weight of all of the children. This can be used for instance to give a single child 50% of the total available space by giving it a layout_weight of 0.5 and setting the weightSum to 1.0.

Must be a floating point value, such as "1.2".

Comment: ,, i have options 20,10,25 kb and none of above,which option should i consider ?

Comment: ok, maximum page weight is from webpages, it is the size of the page in kilobytes(kb). with android, you will be great with 25kb or more. As far as I know, the only maximum I've ran into is the 1mb limit on copying files from the asset folder. Based on this question and the others you've asked, people may be confused on the terminology you use, so be patient with us.